Dark mode not applied on component
I am trying to use the Dropdown from NextUI and I already configured the dark mode as per the Dark mode
I use the Dropdown but it applies using the light theme, but as per the docs, the following dark box is applied:

So my version I try to apply dark mode:
// app/layout.tsx


export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <React.StrictMode>
      <html lang="en">
        <body className={inter.className}>
          <NextUIProvider>
            <main className="dark text-foreground bg-background min-h-screen p-4 md:p-24">
              <Header />
              {children}
              <Footer />
            </main>
          </NextUIProvider>
        </body>
      </html>
    </React.StrictMode>
  );
}


And create a dropdown:
// app/_components/nav.tsx


export default function Nav() {
  
  return (
    <Card className="mb-5 p-0">
      <CardBody className="flex flex-row py-3 px-4 w-full">
        <div className="flex flex-auto flex-row space-x-4 ">
          ... some buttons ...
        </div>
        <div className="flex flex-auto flex-row-reverse">
          <div className="flex items-center gap-4">
            <Dropdown
              backdrop="blur"
              showArrow
              radius="sm"
              classNames={{
                base: "before:bg-default-200", // change arrow background
                content: "p-0 border-small border-divider ",
              }}
            >
              <DropdownTrigger>
                <Button variant="ghost">Open Menu</Button>
              </DropdownTrigger>
              <DropdownMenu>
                <DropdownItem>View</DropdownItem>
              </DropdownMenu>
            </Dropdown>
          </div>
        </div>
      </CardBody >
    </Card >
  )
}

Result is the Dropdown is white, which I wish black...:

Edit (26th August):
As per @xxnikosxx question, if I tried using ´dark´ class directly on the components, which did work.
I added the class dark directly to the Dropdown, DropdownMenu and DropdownItem:
export default function Nav() {

  return (
    <Card className="mb-5 p-0">
      <CardBody className="flex flex-row py-3 px-4 w-full">
        <div className="flex flex-auto flex-row space-x-4 ">
          <!-- ...some buttons... -->
        </div>
        <div className="flex flex-auto flex-row-reverse">
          <div className="flex items-center gap-4">
            <Dropdown
              radius="sm"
              classNames={{
                content: "dark text-white p-0 border-small border-divider ", // here
              }}
            >
              <DropdownTrigger>
                <Button variant="ghost">Open Menu</Button>
              </DropdownTrigger>
              <DropdownMenu className="dark">                               // here
                <DropdownItem className="dark">View</DropdownItem>          // here
              </DropdownMenu>
            </Dropdown>
          </div>
        </div>
      </CardBody >
    </Card >
  )
}

And the result is the same as per the docs:


Are you trying to have both light and dark mode, or just dark?

just dark mode.

have you tried adding the "dark" classname to your dropdown component?

let me know so I can submit it as an answer pls ^^

@xXnikosXx - why not post it as an answer if you believe that's all it takes?

@xXnikosXx feel free to post it, it worked. thank you :)

@JaromandaX can't say you ain't right...

Posting the answer since it worked after comment conversation - apply .dark to the components itself since you only want to have dark mode
for reference, if you wanted to have both light and dark mode, you can use .dark: to change classnames for dark mode only.
